# Magento system log

Tags: magento-1.9

> Notice: Undefined index: files  in
>   app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Translate.php on line 138
>           2016-04-01T11:11:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Translate.php
>   on line 216

**Line : 138**

```
foreach ($this->getModulesConfig() as $moduleName=>$info) {
            $info = $info->asArray();
            $this->_loadModuleTranslation($moduleName, $info['files'], $forceReload);
        }
```

**Line:216**

```
protected function _loadModuleTranslation($moduleName, $files, $forceReload=false)
    {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file = $this->_getModuleFilePath($moduleName, $file);
            $this->_addData($this->_getFileData($file), $moduleName, $forceReload);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

It automatically create i don't know why

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem, one of your module declares translation files in its `config.xml` like this:

```
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Vendor_Module>
                <files>
                    <default>Vendor_Module.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Vendor_Module>
        </modules>
    </translate>
```

But the `<files>` tag seems to be missing.

To find the module causing the problem, you can add the following code in the `_loadModuleTranslation` method:

```
Mage::log($moduleName);
```

Right before

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
```

Once you've found out the module causing the problem, check the `config.xml` file and fix the way the translation file is declared.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: @Kothari what are you not getting ?

Comment: What mistake i done

Comment: @Kothari well I just told you in my answer. One of the modules installed on your website is declaring translation files but the `<files>` tag is missing. Use the code I pasted to find which module and if you don't find the error, paste the `config.xml` in your OP